# Equivalent of "so much (as that)" in this context?

Tags: adverbes, locutions

Would I make use of *tant/autant* here to translate these types of sentences?

- "It's not that I don't like to read **so much** as that I just don't
  like this book."
- "It's not that I'm not interested in going, **so much** as that I'm
  overbooked that day and won't be able to make it.
- "It's not **so much** that I don't want to do it, as that I don't
  know how."
- "It's not **so much** that I dislike mustard, as that I just don't
  want any on my hot dog."

Comment: Il y des gros problèmes de grammaire ici quant au sens. On dirait: ***It's not so much that I don't like to read, it's that I just don't like this book.*** Parce que "I don't like to read so much" veut dire: Je n'aime pas beaucoup lire" Et non pas: Ce n'est pas tellement que je n'aime pas lire mais (plutôt) que je n'aime pas ce livre.

Comment: As a native speaker, I would say it this way, or the way you suggested, in everyday life. The meaning is really the same, it’s just a matter of context I’d say. Those who answered knew what I was getting at and didn’t seem to be confused, but you’re right that I could’ve worded it a little better.

Comment: I am a native English speaker. All those sentences are somewhat off. That said, the word tellement comes to mind for some ways of expressing those sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain words have to be added in French; "it" refers to a fact or a cause and that idea has to figure in the sentence in terms of an explicit word. This principle can be done away with by changing somewhat the form in French, explicitly, by using an infinitive clause. It is possible to use an infinitive clause and a clause with a finite verb form; all the possibilities ob combinations are not given.

- 1/ Ce n'est pas **tant dû au fait** que je n'aime pas lire  qu'**au fait** que je n'aime  tout simplement pas  ce livre.
  2/ Ce n'est pas **tant le fait** que je n'aime pas lire  que **le fait** que je n'aime  tout simplement pas  ce livre.
  3/  Ce n'est pas **tant**  de ne pas aimer lire  que   de ne tout simplement pas aimer   ce livre.

- 1/ Ce n'est pas **tant dû au fait** que je ne suis pas intéressé par y aller qu'**au fait** que tout mon temps est pris ce jour-là et que je ne vais pas pouvoir faire ça.
  2/ Ce n'est pas **tant**  de ne pas être intéressé par y aller que de ne pas avoir de temps libre ce jour-là et de ne  pas pouvoir faire ça.

- 1/ Ce n'est pas **tant** de ne pas vouloir le faire que **dû au fait** que je ne sais pas comment.
  2/ Ce n'est pas **tant**  de ne pas vouloir le faire que de ne pas savoir comment.

- 1/ Ce n'est pas **tant** que la moutarde  me déplait que **le fait** que je n'en veux pas dans mon hot-dog.
  2/  Ce n'est pas **tant** de ne pas aimer la moutarde que de ne pas en vouloir dans mon hot-dog.
  3/  Ce n'est pas **tant** que la moutarde  me déplait que de ne pas en vouloir dans mon hot-dog.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, it seems correct to me...

Comment: I agree, and I upvoted this as well. I do have an unrelated question though: this answer uses sur as the preposition before hotdog, and the first answer uses dans. Are they both correct?

Comment: @tssmith2425 We must realise one thing: in English the hot dog is the saussage ittself, whereas in French it is different; here is the dictionary definition: Petit pain fourré d'une saucisse chaude, relevée ou non de moutarde. Therefore, what is correct is "dans" and I''ll make that correction right away.

Answer (score 7):

There are some different ways to translate **so much** even if contexts seem to be the same in your examples. But, I think in every case you could say "mais seulement".

Here are few examples:

> "It's not that I don't like to read so much as that I just don't like this book."

"Ce n'est pas que je n'aime pas lire, mais seulement je n'aime pas ce livre."

> "It's not that I'm not interested in going, so much as that I'm
>       overbooked that day and won't be able to make it.

"Ce n'est pas que je n'ai pas envie de venir, mais plutôt que je serai très occupé  ce même jour et il me sera donc impossible de venir."

> "It's not so much that I don't want to do it, as that I don't
>       know how."

"Non pas que je n'ai pas envie de le faire, mais plutôt que je ne sais pas comment le faire."

> "It's not so much that I dislike mustard, as that I just don't
>       want any on my hot dog."

"Ce n'est pas tellement que je n'aime pas la moutarde, mais je n'en veux pas dans mon *hot dog*, c'est tout."

Comment: These are perfect, and they get the exact meaning across, so thank you very much. I’ve never seen “il me sera” used like this before, but google tells me it’s literally “it will be (impossible) for me.”

Comment: Actually you're right, it's another way to say "il sera donc impossible pour moi de venir". The reflexive pronoun "me" overrides "pour moi" ;)

Comment: Eh bien, j’espère qu’il me sera impossible d’oublier. ;)

Comment: Il faut faire la différence entre verbe + autant (lire autant) et tellement. L'anglais confond ces deux choses et aucune des 4 phrases n'est bien dite.

Comment: Je ne vois pas d'ambigüité ici, étant donné la seconde partie de la phrase à chaque fois. Ayant lu votre réponse, je veux bien vous croire qu'elle existe parfois et il peut être intéressant d'en discuter sur english.stackexchange.com, soit en réponse à une question existante, soit en posant la question et en se répondant soi-même. Cela aurait aussi permis d'avertir la personne concernée directement en commentaire de la réponse en fournissant le lien adéquat. Mais en effet, dur dur de faire avec les egos de chacun et j'en suis le premier désolé que ça ait tourné en vinaigre :/

Comment: @LPH It was missing form the last sentence indeed, I've corrected it, thanks. But in the third sentence, I used "Non pas que..." to point out an other way of translating that idea of "so much", that 's why you can't see "tant". And regarding the two first sentences, the use of "so much" differs.

Comment: @purerstamp « Non pas que » est une locution conjonctive, il manque donc une principale dans votre phrase.  Il faut, il me semble, une négation: « non pas que je **n**'ai pas envie ». Aussi, le degré de l'envie de faire est absolu (je n'ai pas envie), alors que ce qui est dit est ceci : j'ai un peu envie de ne pas le faire mais ce qui m'arrête surtout c'est que je ne sais pas comment.

Comment: @LPH La négation est déjà marquée par "Non pas que". Voir https://journals.openedition.org/linx/1214 (§16 du texte intégral et annexes 3,4,13, etc)

Comment: On peut être rassuré sur ce point de négation, vous avez raison ; on prend l'exemple simple de la source que vous introduisez, « Alors je me suis dit que j’irais me coucher : non pas que j’avais sommeil. Il n’était que huit heures. ». Selon cette forme sans négation la conclusion est « Je n'avais pas sommeil. ». De façon analogue on doit avoir pour la conclusion de votre phrase « Je n'ai pas envie de le faire. »

Comment: @LPH J'ai mis la négation en fin de phrase à chaque fois il me semble, non ? D'ailleurs je dois avouer que j'ai voté pour votre réponse à cette question il y a bien longtemps déjà ^_^ En tout cas merci pour cet échange qui m'a permis d'affiner quelques points :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed in the other answer ("Ce n'est pas que je n'aime pas lire, mais seulement je n'aime pas ce livre.") is quite correct.

There is an other possibility, more formal:

"Ce n'est pas tant que je n'aime pas lire, plutôt que je n'aime pas ce livre."

The advantage of this proposal is that *tant* here corresponds to the original *so much*, as *tant* introduces a notion of quantity too.

Answer (score 2):

1) « It's not that I don't like to **read so much** as that I just don't like this book. »

2) De l'anglais courant ici serait :

"***It's not so much that I don't like to read*, it's just that I just don't like this book**."

3)  *(traduction de la phrase précédente*)
 ***Ce n'est pas tellement* que je n'aime pas lire, c'est que ce livre ne me plait pas.**

4) Et il faut faire attention à ne pas confondre la phrase 1) avec

"I don't like **to read so much**, I prefer to read less."

5) Cette dernière phrase donne en français :

« **Je n'aime pas lire autant**, je préfère lire moins. ».

Il faut faire attention où l'on place « so much » en anglais, puisque cela peut donner un verbe + autant ou bien l'adverbe tellement.

Cela dit, *so much as that*  tel qu'écrit dans les quatres phrases du posteur ne relèvent pas d'un style acceptable autre que dans certains parlers populaires. On entend des phrases pareilles mais elles ne sont pas vraiment bien construites.

Par ailleurs, je ne critique personne, mais il me semblait juste de faire remarquer ces structures puisqu'il vaut mieux éviter les phrases fourre-tout, n'est-ce pas?

Mon intention était de rendre clairement les propositions en anglais d'abord pour ensuite les traduire.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to say (and I appreciate it), but even though you’re not trying to critique anyone, it does slightly feel that way. The way I initially wrote it essentially is just another way of saying the same thing. My third and fourth constructions I think avoid the confusion though, since I changed the placement of “so much.” I do want to assert though that my sentences are not poorly constructed. I’ve been saying similar things and have heard them constantly throughout my life.

Comment: Seulement « on entend de pareilles phrases » ou  « on entend de**s** phrases pareilles ».

Comment: Also, shouldn’t 5) say “je n’aime pas tant lire ...” ? Because “lire autant” seems to me to say “read as much,” and then my brain wants there to be a comparison following. So this seems incorrect.

Comment: La critique est vraiment ce pourquoi on écrit à propos des langues sur les sites de langue ; nous sommes là pour critiquer et être critiqués (dans le domaine de la langue) ; vous avez donc bien formulé une critique ; la critique est constructive, on doit s'habituer dans ce domaine à voir nos plus chères convictions rejetées et elles peuvent l'être pour toujours : on ne peut que les défendre du mieux possible et c'est tout ce que l'on doive faire. Ceci dit, je suis assez convaincu que votre formulation se lit beaucoup plus clairement, c'est une amélioration.

Comment: I was mildly irritated because Lambie left a few comments in which they said my phrases weren’t well constructed, while they’re actually fine. It would be one thing if users here were confused about my intended meaning and didn’t know how to answer appropriately, but everyone knew what I meant and responded accordingly, so Lambie’s responses correcting me seemed pedantic. I will say though that I hadn’t taken into account the placement of “so much,” and I can see how that could be confusing, so for that I’m thankful.

Comment: @tssmith2425 « Je n'aime pas tant lire » and « Je n'aime pas lire autant » are synonymous; they are assertions about the quantity of reading as compared to a reference that comes before (Jean lit un livre par mois, je n'aime pas lire autant/tant.); [(TLFi) Rem. 1. Dans les prop. négatives, on peut employer tant au lieu de autant. Le tour est fam.] in English that would have to be "I don't like to read so/as much."

Comment: @tssmith2425 However, "I don't like to read so much." is ambiguous in English: DeepL confirms that, we get "Je n'aime pas trop lire." and "je n'aime pas lire autant."; it seems to me that I internalised the two meanings. So, there would be justification in lambie's point of view.

Comment: @Lambie you raise a valid point. What frustrates me though is your consistent assertion that I’ve written a grammatically incorrect and inaccurate sentence (or sentences). One of the beauties of language is poetic license, and that you can play around with words and convey the same meaning in different ways, or different meanings all together. That’s a bit of a stretch, as I’m not writing poetry here, but certain placements do have flexibility. I just feel like you were leaving comment after comment asserting that I was incorrect; it just didn’t feel very good.

Comment: @tssmith2425 Of course, one can play around with anything. But you write them out **as if** they were standard parlance. Frankly, I think my suggested restructuring of "not so much that x but that I y" is more common than "as that". Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Lambie they have been standard parlance in my life. If they aren’t to you, then that boils down to the environment in which we respectively have lived or grown up in. Your restructuring is more accurate for sure, and I admit I struggled to figure out the best way to word it. I was thrown off by how you went about it. Also, I still feel that asserting that your French is better than their English is taking liberties. Truthfully you don’t know what their level is. I deleted my other comments because that’s not the kind of person I’d like to be.

Comment: @Lambie also, your comments and answers are always welcome on my future posts and questions, just so you know. I appreciate your feedback now that I have come down from my pedestal and my stubbornness subsided. Haha.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Make no mistake about it, I never said that the poster's "way of speaking" is non-standard. I said the **sentence structure was non-standard** or meant that and even the poster has now seen that. People speak how they speak. Period. No criticism of people's actual speech.

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping the double negatives *not that I don't*, *not that I'm not* etc. make for very heavy French, I would avoid it altogether and probably say :

"It's not that I don't like to read so much as that I just don't like this book."

> J'aime lire, c'est pas ça la question, mais ce livre, non.

"It's not that I'm not interested in going, so much as that I'm
overbooked that day and won't be able to make it.

> Je voudrais bien y aller, c'est pas ça le problème, mais ce jour-là, j'ai déjà plein de choses de prévues et je peux pas.

"It's not so much that I don't want to do it, as that I don't
know how."

> J'aurais bien envie de le faire, mais je sais pas comment.

"It's not so much that I dislike mustard, as that I just don't
want any on my hot dog."

> J'aime la moutarde, c'est pas ça, mais pas sur ma saucisse.